# Как настроить reCAPTCHA для формы с method="GET"?

Tags: post, get, recaptcha

Здравствуйте! На моем сайте работает только форма с method="GET". В документации к reCAPTCHA используются только формы с method="POST". Как заставить работать Google reCAPTCHA с GET методом?

Comment: очевидно никак.

Comment: лучше в скрипте сделайте что бы и POST и GET принимал.